# Why can't you add border-radius to a Button in Android directly like in HTML/CSS?

Tags: android

In Android you have to create a `drawable` background with `<corners>` to create a border radius effect on a View. There is no XML attribute `borderRadius` like in HTML/CSS.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `why` is bit too deep to answer I reckon. 
However, I can point you to `stroke` attribute, have you had a look at it? I feel it achieves the same effect. Essentially, you can add a border to any shape using `stroke`. E.g..

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="#fefefe" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```